# How to query number of different ratings (not reviews!) from App Store

Tags: app-store, itunes

Is there any API that allows to query the number of ratings from the Apple App Store?

I know that `http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews...` can be used to get a list of **reviews**. But since a **rating** (selecting stars 1-5) does not require to write a review (additional text added to the rating), the number of reviews is not the same as the number of ratings. An app could have hundreds of ratings without having a single review.

I know that one can use `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=SomeID` to get the total number of ratings and the average rating of the current version, e.g. "100 ratings with an average of 4 stars".

But I am looking for a solution to get the number of different rating, e.g.

```
60 x 5 stars 
20 x 4 stars 
10 x 3 stars 
 7 x 2 stars
 3 x 1 stars
```

Is there any (more or less) official way of getting these concrete star ratings without reverse engineering the iTunes protocol and without using any paid third party APIs?